# XSLT adding a tr at nth position while transforming the XML node with different child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT, and I am trying to transform the below XML. Note that the child nodes will be different

```
<parent>
 <child1>A</child1>
 <child2>B</child2>
 <child3>C</child3>
 <child4>D</child4>
 <child5>E</child5>
 <child6>F</child6>
 <child7>G</child7>
</parent>
```

I want transform the above as follows,when n is 3

```
<tr><td>child1:A</td><td>child2:B</td><td>child3:C</td></tr>
<tr><td>child4:D</td><td>child5:E</td><td>child6:F</td></tr>
<tr><td>child7:G</td></tr>
```

I tried as follows

```
<xsl:template match="parent/*[position() mod 4 = 1]">
    <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="proc"
        select=".|following-sibling::parent/*[not(position() > 3)]"
    />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="parent/*[not(position() mod 4 = 1)]"/>
 <xsl:template match="parent/*" mode="proc">
    <td class="label"><xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>:<xsl:value-of select ="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post your try here.

Comment: use lowercase `parent` instead of PARENT, xml and xslt are case-sensitive

Comment: @StefanHegny, I tried modifying the PARENT to parent (lowercase) , still it is not output all the nodes as expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line...

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="proc"
                     select=".|following-sibling::parent/*[not(position() > 3)]" />
```

You are in a template matching a child of the parent element (`parent/*)`. This means the current node does not have a `parent` node as a sibling. Change the expression to this

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="proc" 
                     select=".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > 3)]" />
```